# Wrap text in vertical menu

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

This is my simple code of menu

```
  <ul id="admin-ul">
    <li id="admin-li" class="no1"><a href="dodaj.php">Dodaj informacije za sdf dsf dsfdddd</a></li>
    <li id="admin-li" class="no2"><a href="pregledaj.php">Pregledaj</a></li>
    <li id="admin-li" class="no3"><a href="veterinari.php">Veterinari</a></li>
    <li id="admin-li" class="no4"><a href="../logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and CSS

```
ul#admin-ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li#admin-li
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:24%;
    height:270px;
}

ul li a
{
    display:block;
    height:270px;
    line-height:270px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I would like to know how to wrap my text because it is showing like this [image]

Comment: It technically is wrapping, you just have the line height the same height as the container div, so the next line will be 540px below the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
ul#admin-ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:1em 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}

li#admin-li
{
    display:table;
    width:24%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:270px;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

ul li a
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:270px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Derived from here: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

This doesn't work in IE7 standard mode, but pretty much everything else is good.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `vertical-align: top` on your `<li>`s. Please note that all ids must be unique so this is invalid HTML:

```
<li id="admin-li" class="no1"><a href="dodaj.php"></a></li>
<li id="admin-li" class="no1"><a href="dodaj.php"></a></li>
```

You can style all `<li>`s more easily using the child selector like this:

```
ul#admin-ul > li {
    /* other li rules */
    vertical-algin: top;
}
```

You can than update your list to this:

```
<ul id="admin-ul">
    <li class="no1"><a href="dodaj.php"></a></li>
    <li class="no1"><a href="dodaj.php"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Final demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eXKdG/

*<sub>Update</sub>*

As I didn't notice the vertical centering of the text within the block level `<a>`-tag: [tesdki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854803/tedski) is right in simply using `display: table-cell;` on the `<a>`-tags.

Comment: This has the same problem, if you make the "Dodaj" line exceed the width then it bumps it down past the bottom of the box. http://jsfiddle.net/eXKdG/2/

Comment: You're right and thanks for pointing that out. I didn't even notice that huge `line-height`. I thought it's just about the vertical alignment of the boxes.